# Convergence of integral under a limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Background: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two lognormal random variables, and $Z = X|Y = y$ a lognormal random variable obtained by conditioning on $Y$. Denote by $g_{\rho}(z)$ the probability density function of $Z$ for a fixed $\rho \in [0,1]$, where $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$.

Let $f(z)$ be an extended-real valued and Lipschitz continuous function with $z \in [-\infty,\infty]$. Define $$I (\rho) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)g_{\rho}(z) dz.$$

At $\rho = 1$,  we have $g_{\rho}(z) = 1(z = \mathbb{E}[Z])$, where $1(\cdot)$ denotes the indicator function. As a result, $I(1) = f(\mathbb{E}[Z])$.

Desired result: $$\lim_{\rho \to 1}I(\rho) = I(1) = f(\mathbb{E}[Z])$$.

Issue: The limit affects the distribution in the integral. The theorems that I am aware of in this situation, such as Portmanteau's Theorem, require boundedness and continuity of $f$. In my case the function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous but unbounded. I wonder if there are alternate results that could be leveraged here or if the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz is useful. Any help on proving this result is much appreciated.